# My Search is Working On Main Page But Not The Other

Tags: css

I have a website. I have used a search bar on the top next to the logo. Whenever we type something the search works and is redirected to the appropriate page but in a video playback page or you can say on any other page the search does not works.

First, try it on main page and it works.

http://www.trueflick.com

On any other page or video playback page like this it will not work.

trueflick.com/videos/277/6-dreamcast-facts-which-makes-it-awesome-factsurgery/

Although the code is same. Here is the CSS code which is used in CSS file.

```
#search {

}

#search input[type="text"] {
    background: url(search-white.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #fcfcfc;
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    }

#search input[type="text"]:focus {
    width: 300px;
    }
```

Comment: This isn't a CSS issue, it has to do with your HTML or Javascript. You are not closing your search ```<form>```s, you should try that first. Is there any Javascript that interacts with your search form inputs?

Comment: Have you noticed your search box is working fine in firefox but not in Chrome!

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one form with matching IDs (`search`) as well as `input`s with matching names of `q`.  Get rid of the second one further down the page (or rename the `form` and `input` elements)

I tested this in Chrome and was able to search once I deleted the conflicting node.

Don't forget your closing `</form>` each time.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Closing the form tag resolved the issue. I have also removed the other search bar.

Comment: splendid.  feel free to accept/upvote if you are able and willing :)